# Remote gradle build daemon

Tags: gradle

This is in context of a CICD system. Is there any way to have a remote, long lived gradle daemon that does not live on the same box as the gradle client? I.E a daemon that I can call over the network w/ the local gradle CLI

Answer (score 0):

No, Gradle does not (yet) support distributing builds to remote machines. There is a hint from the developers [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7614) that suggests that the feature might come eventually.